# Rollback on a tag wiki isn't working

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, rollbacks

Yesterday, I tried to rollback on the CSS tag wiki:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3644669/revisions

When I click "rollback", and click "OK" to "Are you sure you want to rollback?", nothing happens.

An error appears in Chrome's console:

[image]