# Cannot rollback tag wiki excerpt edit

Tags: bug, tag-wiki-excerpt, 404-not-found

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rollback on a tag wiki isn’t working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135998/rollback-on-a-tag-wiki-isnt-working)

I attempted to rollback a [bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted) [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/588187/) for the PHP tag wiki excerpt from the [excerpt history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3624936/revisions) page, and it failed with a 404 response when it tried to post to this URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3624936/rollback/5b25b725-2f0f-452f-9112-76f156b775f4

With these parameters:

```
fkey    48ee261e98c8bbf32bd3a45d3244af73
```

Comment: The tag excerpt has been rolled back.